# mysqli num_rows expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Olá, sou iniciante em PHP e MySQL e estou precisando de ajuda.

Estou recebendo o erro que está no título da pergunta na minha função de login:

```
    public function login ($login, $senha) {
    $result = $this->conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' and senha='$senha';");
    if(!$result->execute()){
        echo 'erro: '. $result->error;
    }
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0){
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='Teste.php';</script>";
    }else{
        setcookie("login", $login);
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

}
```

A variável $result está recebendo somente valor 0 e eu não estou conseguindo resolver, se alguém puder me ajudar a solucionar, estou grato desde já.

Comment: o user que esta a usar existe na bd? tem certeza que a password está correcta?

Comment: Sim. o user é 'teste' e a senha também, já tentei inserir diretamente com: SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='teste' and senha='teste';. Mas ainda sim ele retorna 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que executar o **`store_result`** e de preferencia se vai usar OOP então use tudo assim, não tem porque na API do mysqli misturar procedural com OOP (falo somente desta API, o resto do PHP é questão de gosto e necessidade, ai pode "misturar"):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' and senha='$senha';")) {

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='Teste.php';</script>";
    } else {
        setcookie("login", $login);
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

---

Outra coisa muito importante, por que usar variaveis com `prepare` diretamente na string? (não precisa responder)

Se quer evitar que alguém passe um valor para login ou password que cause erro de sintaxe ou até mesmo um **sql-injetcion** use diretamente o `bind_param`, porque esse é o objetivo do `prepare`, assim:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login=? and senha=?")) {

    /* passa os valores na ordem dos interrogações */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $login, $senha);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='Teste.php';</script>";
    } else {
        setcookie("login", $login);
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!

Eu ainda estou um pouco confuso com os métodos de banco de dados e OOP, ainda estou aprendendo, mas muito obrigado pela explicação!